# iOS 11 Google Map SDK Current Location not working proper

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios11, google-maps-sdk-ios, currentlocation

i have implemented Google Map SDK and it is working fine in iOS < 11 version but in iOS >=11 version it is stuck on old location longtime or moving near by location sometimes

is it iOS issue or Google map sdk issue??

thanks in advance

Comment: You can't move the map on iOS >= 11 ?

Comment: i am moving but sometimes displaying old location and sometimes stop moving on old location. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8112686

Comment: share your code. and mention what are you trying to do.